postfix sasl authentication not working - testsaslauthd shows different result with -u"user@realm" vs -u"user" and -r"realm"
I'm setting up a postfix smtp relay with saslauthd authentication on Ubuntu 24.04. I've set up postfix to use sasl, but the sasl authentication from my mail server to the relay is not working.
I don't think it's a configuration problem between postfix and sasl - Postfix is definitely authenticating against sasl. The error in the mail log is:
2024-07-31T13:33:52.405993+00:00 smtp postfix/smtpd[4188]: connect from mail.domain.tld[X.X.X.X]
2024-07-31T13:33:52.524758+00:00 smtp postfix/smtpd[4188]: warning: mail.domain.tld[X.X.X.X]: SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure, sasl_username=user@realm
2024-07-31T13:33:52.540845+00:00 smtp postfix/smtpd[4188]: disconnect from mail.domain.tld[X.X.X.X] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=4/5

output of sasldblistusers2:
user@realm: userPassword

I expect to be able to authenticate my mail server - mail.domain.tld - in postfix running on my smtp relay - smtp.domain.tld.
When setting up the sasl user, I did the following:
saslpasswd2 -c -u smtp.domain.tld user

What I am not understanding is why, when testing sasl, I get the following output:
root@smtp:~|⇒ testsaslauthd -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux -u"user" -r"smtp.domain.tld" -p"password"
0: OK "Success."

BUT - and this is why I think authentication is failing -
root@smtp:~|⇒  testsaslauthd -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux -u"user@smtp.domain.tld" -p"password"    
0: NO "authentication failed"

/etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_banner                    = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff                            = no
append_dot_mydomain             = no
readme_directory                = no
compatibility_level             = 3.6
myhostname                      = smtp.domain.tld
mydomain                        = domain.tld
# TLS parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
smtpd_tls_cert_file             = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file              = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level        = may
smtp_tls_CApath                 = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level         = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions        = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
# SASL setup
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_path                 = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_local_domain         = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients        = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options     = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination

alias_maps                      = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database                  = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination                   = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost                       =
mynetworks                      = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit              = 0
recipient_delimiter             = +
inet_interfaces                 = all
inet_protocols                  = all


/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 NTLM

/etc/systemd/system/saslauthd-postfix.service
[Unit]
Description=SASL Authentication Daemon for Postfix
Documentation=man:saslauthd(8)

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/saslauthd-postfix
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saslauthd -a $MECHANISMS $MECH_OPTIONS $OPTIONS -n $THREADS
RuntimeDirectory=saslauthd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

/etc/default/saslauthd-postfix
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon for Postfix"
NAME="saslauthd-pstfx"
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"

